# Include Statement is Not working is there any nugget packages to install?

Tags: c#

```
var randomQuestionID=_context.questions
    .Include(q => q.Answers)
    .Where(e => e.Id == range.ElementAt(RandomQuestionId))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Here is the code and there is a relationship between the two tables and the other thing the include statement is working in my friends PC with the same code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should show what you have included at the top, for example `using System;`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please give more details about what you mean by "is not working". Does it compile but throw an exception? Give the wrong results? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are using EntityFramework Core, you need:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Otherwise you need:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Comment: thanks it worked i were using System.Data.Entity when i change to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore it works